# Using Parameter within timestamp_trunc in SQL Query for DataStudio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to use a custom parameter within DataStudio. The data is hosted in BigQuery.

```
SELECT    
timestamp_trunc(o.created_at, @groupby) AS dateMain,
count(o.id) AS total_orders
FROM `x.default.orders` o
group by 1
```

When I try this, it returns an error saying that "A valid date part name is required at [2:35]"

I basically need to group the dates using a parameter (e.g. day, week, month).

I have also included a screenshot of how I have created the parameter in Google DataStudio. There is a default value set which is "day".

[image]

Comment: You are trying to use an array as input in the TIMESTAMP_TRUNC() function, which cannot be. Standard SQL is expecting a datepart (DAY, MONTH, etc).

Comment: How would we group our date data by week? There seems to be out of the box functionality to group by month and year but not by week within data studio.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that might do the trick here is to use a [rollup in the group by](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#:%7E:text=GROUP%20BY%20ROLLUP,like%20this%20one%3A) with the different levels of aggregation of the date, since I am not sure you can pass a DS parameter to work like that.

See the following example for clarity:

```
with default_orders as (
  select timestamp'2021-01-01' as created_at, 1 as id
  union all
  select timestamp'2021-01-01', 2
  union all
  select timestamp'2021-01-02', 3
  union all
  select timestamp'2021-01-03', 4
  union all
  select timestamp'2021-01-03', 5
  union all
  select timestamp'2021-01-04', 6
),
final as (
  select
    count(id) as count_orders,
    timestamp_trunc(created_at, day) as days,
    timestamp_trunc(created_at, week) as weeks,
    timestamp_trunc(created_at, month) as months
  from
    default_orders
  group by
    rollup(days, weeks, months)
    
)
select * from final
```

The output, then, would be similar to the following:

```
count | days       | weeks    | months
------+------------+----------+----------
 6    |  null      |  null    |  null       <- this, represents the overall (counted 6 ids)
 2    |  2021-01-01|  null    |  null       <- this, the 1st rollup level (day)
 2    |  2021-01-01|2020-12-27|  null       <- this, the 1st and 2nd (day, week)
 2    |  2021-01-01|2020-12-27|2021-01-01   <- this, all of them
```

And so on.

At the moment of visualizing this on data studio, you have two options: setting the metric as Avg instead of Sum, because as you can see there's kind of a duplication at each stage of the `day column`; or doing another step in the query and get rid of nulls, like this:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  final 
where 
  days is not null and
  weeks is not null and
  months is not null
```